# Monster, Baby Monster: 196,883 and 4371 dimensions = hexadecimal 30113 and 1113: similarity has a reason, or mere numerological coincidence?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Representations of the Baby Monster group and Monster group have dimensions 4371 and 196 883, respectively.

In base-16 (hexadecimal), these numbers become `1113` and `30113`, respectively.

Two things stand out:

1. They share the same paucity of distinct hexadecimal digits (`1` and `3`).
2. They share the same final three digits: `...113`, so they're congruent modulo 16<sup>3</sup> = 2<sup>12</sup>.

Looking at further terms of [OEIS A001378](https://oeis.org/A001378) and [OEIS A001379](https://oeis.org/A001379), the fourth terms also have this congruency modulo 2<sup>12</sup>:

- A001378(4) = 1 139 374 = `...2ae` in hexadecimal
- A001379(4) = 842 609 326 = `...2ae` in hexadecimal

The above isn't applicable to the other terms. Nevertheless, for what it's worth, we also have:

- A001378(3) − A001378(2) = 96 255 − 4371 = 91 884 = `...6ec` in hexadecimal
- A001379(3) = 21 296 876 = `...6ec` in hexadecimal

I hesitated a long time before posting numerological nonsense to a math forum, but a weak pretext is that monstrous moonshine itself sprung from a numerical coincidence. Unlike moonshine, I'm sure all this doesn't have any actual significance, but it's been bugging me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid it looks like numerology to me. To explain the first one, we remember that the double cover of $BM$, i.e., $2\cdot BM$, is a subgroup of $M$, so the characters of $M$ restrict to sums of characters of $2\cdot BM$. There are very few small character degrees of both groups, and it is easy to check (even without restricting the character!) that
$$196883=1+4371+96255+96256.$$
(The last of these is a faithful character for $2\cdot BM$, the others are not.) You are interested in $196883-4371$, which is simply $2\cdot 96256=2^{12}\cdot 47$.

Lots of characters of quasisimple groups $2\cdot S$ for $S$ simple have a large power of $2$ dividing their degree, it's not that uncommon. And it is often true that there are characters of $S$ that are of degree $1$ less than one of $2\cdot S$.